# Function inside of directive runs twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which is used in 5 different views.  I have my directive inside the view, then in the directive I add a specific function for each scope where directive is represented.  Afterwards, I am able to call this function on click of a button which is part of the template in the directive.  But for some reason, the function inside directive is called more than once.

Here is the directive code:

```
app.directive('testDirective', function ($parse, $state, $compile) {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        restrict: 'E',
        //transclude: false,
        replace: true,
        template: "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary pull-left ' data-dismiss='modal' ng-click='myFunnyFunction()'>func</button>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.testData = data;

            scope.myFunnyFunction = function () {
                console.log(scope.testData)
                //some stuff done here
            }
        }
    };

    return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

Is it because of digest cycle?

Comment: seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rd13/eTTZj/613/, can you add some more code i.e. how your views are constructed?

Comment: This directive does not seem to have its own scope, so it using that of its parent. See the "Isolating the Scope of a Directive" @ http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I really dont know why... but when i removed replace: true, it works fine now, any idea why?!

Comment: may be you are compiling the directive div again, somewhere else.